# UWP: how to hide a RelativePanel after 2 seconds

Tags: xaml, uwp, hide, padding, visualstatemanager

I have developed an UWP app allowing users to edit forms.
I would like to use a **RelativePanel** to **show messages** to the users on the **Home** page.
Theses message can concern forms management ("*The form XXX has well been deleted*", "*The form XXX has well been saved*"), or the synchronization ("*Sync ended successfully*", "*Impossible to sync datas*").

The **Home** page is based on a Grid that contains 3 rows:

- a filter searchbox
- the list of the forms
- sync informations

Here is a screenshot of this page:
[image: Home]

I would like to display the RelativePanel in the 3rd Row, above the sync informations, but **only during 2 seconds**. Then the RelativePanel will disappear, and the sync informations must be visible again.

I also encounter a **problem** with the width of the RelativePanel: I would like a **left/right padding of 150**, but it doesn't seem to work:
[image: Home with RelativePanel]

My XAML code looks like this:

```
<!-- User + Last sync-->
<Grid Grid.Row="2">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentUser.username}" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <TextBlock x:Uid="HomeTextBlockLastSync" Margin="0,0,8,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastSync, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>

<!-- Form Status message -->
<RelativePanel Grid.Row="2" 
               Background="Cyan"
               Padding="150,0,150,0">
    <StackPanel x:Name="FormStatusPanel" Orientation="Vertical" 
                    RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                    RelativePanel.AlignVerticalCenterWithPanel="True">
        <Border x:Name="FormStatusBorder" Margin="0">
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollMode="Auto"  
                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                          MaxHeight="150">
                <TextBlock Text="TestTestTest"
                           x:Name="FormStatusBlock" FontWeight="Bold"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</RelativePanel>
```

***=> Would you have an idea on why the Padding doesn't work? What is a better way to hide RelativePanel after 2 seconds? With the VisualStateManager or by the code?***

Comment: You can use a [Dispatcher timer][1] and Change the relative panel visibility to collapsed and set the duration to 2secs .


  [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br244250

Comment: Thank you @Pratyay. But is it possible to use the DispatcherTimer in the ViewModel? The message will be initialized through the ViewModel, so where must I use the DispatcherTimer: in the ViewModel or in the Code behind?